# What's the difference between /etc/cron.d and /var/spool/cron?

Tags: linux, redhat, cron

The crontabs on RHEL seem to be duplicated in two places, `/etc/cron.d`, and `/var/spool/cron`. I've checked, and neither of these are simlinks to the other, and neither are any of the crons contained in either location.

I guess my most important question is this, which of these two is the authoritative location? If I were to edit a file in only one of these two, which one would I have to make my edit in to get it to execute?

Comment: Don't forget about /etc/crontab!

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`/var/spool/cron` is where the individual user crontabs live. As user, `crontab -e` edits the corresponding file in `/var/spool/cron`.

`/etc/cron.d` is a directory that is scanned for modular crontab files. The syntax is slightly different for files in that directory. The cron entries have an additional field for a `user` to run the cron entries as. This is the same as a systemwide `/etc/crontab` file.

See RedHat's documentation here: http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/3/html/System_Administration_Guide/ch-autotasks.html

Comment: Adding that the files in /etc/cron.d/ are, in effect, all root-owned (and therefore not user cron files); also, these files are NOT run "by cron" - they are run by a cron **job** that looks at these files.