# Add Cron Job to Several Servers

Tags: linux, cron

What would be the best way to add a new cron job to several servers simultaneously, or to automate the creation of a cron job on several servers.

I am planning on using rysnc to push a bash script out to several servers, but I need to add a cron job that will run this script.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most modern Linux distributions have support for the `/etc/cron.d` framework, which would allow a modular approach to pushing cron "snippets" out to multiple servers. This is a special directory that is scanned every minute for available jobs. You can drop small cron files into the directory. It's a more elegant approach than editing a central or per-user crontab.

See: [What's the difference between /etc/cron.d and /var/spool/cron?](https://serverfault.com/questions/325340/whats-the-difference-between-etc-cron-d-and-var-spool-cron) For more information on the slightly-different format needed to use this framework.

I would create the jobs/cron files and scp them to the relevant servers. I think that for something at this scale, Puppet or a full configuration management suite is overkill.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. Thanks for the support. The files in /etc/cron.d/ are like an extension of the cronttab. One thing to be careful of is that you specify a user to run the job.

Answer (score 6):

You can also consider Ansible, it has cron module.

Comment: I do have to remember to add Ansible to my list of Puppet-alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

Puppet has a cron provider. (probably also CFEngine and Chef and [some of the other options](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Configuration_management))

It also has a neat trick where you can stagger the execution of cron jobs using the hash of the hostname, like this:

```
cron { "run-myscript":
  command => "/path/to/myscript.sh",
  minute => inline_template("<%= hostname.hash.abs % 60 %>"),
}
```

If you have more than a couple of dozen servers or you think you are likely to ever grow to that size, getting started now with configuration management will be worth your while.

For a quick-and-dirty solution, [clusterssh](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/551) might do the trick.  A longer term solution to these sorts of problems would be [MCollective](http://puppetlabs.com/mcollective/introduction/), [Func](https://fedorahosted.org/func/), [Fabric](http://fabfile.org/) or [Capistrano](http://www.capify.org/).

Comment: Without puppet, another quick and dirty solution can be to push files to /etc/cron.d/ (present in most linux distro) using scp and a for loop. But using an scm like puppet is recommended.

Answer (score 0):

I Would write a script that I would put in a samba share that all my server could access, then I will define a the same cron for each and point to the same script!

Answer (score -1):

Should be tried in a proof of concept, but i think it may work with a shared `/var/spool/cron` directory (such as a nfs share). Did you try it ? I would say it would be the easy way

Comment: This is a very bad idea, nfs lacks security. Anyone on network would be able to push script that edit /etc/shadow.

Comment: I'm not sure to get your point. The NFS directory, will have quite the same permissions than a local /var/spool/cron folder unless you are making a reference to ACLs ?

Comment: nfs was designed in 90's, when security was not a concern. It offer no security at all. You can find many examples on the internet : http://www.vulnerabilityassessment.co.uk/nfs.htm